# How do I set a font in Imagick PHP?

Tags: php, fonts, imagick

I can't seem to get Imagick::setFont to work in php.  Taking the example straight from the [man page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setfont.php):

```
/* Create new imagick object */
$im = new Imagick();

/* Set the font for the object */
$im->setFont("comic.ttf");

/* Create new caption */
$im->newPseudoImage(100, 100, "caption:Hello");

$im->setformat('png');
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $im;
```

I get...

[image: hello]
http://i53.tinypic.com/2d2bn9x.png

... which is clearly not comic sans.  I've tried numerous fonts.  It never changes.  It does complain if the file doesn't exist.  It does not accept names like "Arial".

Comment: Is the font file in the same folder as the script? If not the path has to be set correctly...

Comment: @evolve, the font is definitely in the correct location.  If I move it, the script fails.  If it's in the right location, it renders but the font is unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same situation here and I found this post

http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=11937

They say Freetype library should be installed, but haven't tried yet.

**UPDATE**

Finally I had chance to try it and It worked.

I use

ImageMagick 6.7.6

Imagick 3.0

Freetype 2.4.9

Freetype-devel 2.3.11

Fontconfig-devel 2.8

PHP 5.3.13

Answer (score 3):

When you're using setFont method you need to make sure you pass absolute path of the font:

```
$im->setFont("/var/www/html/mysite/media/fonts/myCustomFont.ttf");
```

Same would apply for your localhost development just change the absolute path.

(This is a bit old question but I figured to answer it anyways.)